# How to get the total values of a node properties in a path (Neo4j)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH p =(o:Order)-[r:seeks*2..8]->(o:Order)
WHERE o.Name={orderID} AND ALL(x IN tail(nodes(p)) WHERE 
SINGLE(y IN    tail(nodes(p)) WHERE x=y))
WITH p, o, r, extract(u IN nodes(p)| u.UserName) AS UserName
WHERE size(UserName) - 1 = size(apoc.coll.toSet(tail(UserName)))
RETURN extract(n IN nodes(p)| n.Name) AS OrderID, UserName, length(p) as 
Participants, endNode(r[0]) as AvailableOffers, ***reduce(s = 0, x IN 
extract(b IN nodes(p)| coalesce(b.userReputation, 0)) | s + x) AS UserRep***
ORDER BY length(p)"""
```

[image: The Screenshot of my query result]

I can't get the total of value of properties in a node using reduce function...

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your query, but I think I found your problem is using both reduce and extract.  Try this

```
MATCH p =(o:Order)-[r:seeks*2..8]->(o:Order)
WHERE o.Name={orderID} AND ALL(x IN tail(nodes(p)) WHERE 
SINGLE(y IN    tail(nodes(p)) WHERE x=y))
WITH p, o, r, extract(u IN nodes(p)| u.UserName) AS UserName
WHERE size(UserName) - 1 = size(apoc.coll.toSet(tail(UserName)))
RETURN extract(n IN nodes(p)| n.Name) AS OrderID, UserName, length(p) as 
Participants, endNode(r[0]) as AvailableOffers, ***reduce(s = 0, x IN 
nodes(p)| s + coalesce(x.userReputation, 0)) AS UserRep***
ORDER BY length(p)"""
```